# Zoom div on page load using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to show a div when it is scrolled into view. I would like to simplify this and show the div when the page loads and not when scrolled into view. Any help would be great. Many thanks.

```js
var animateHTML = function () {
  var elems,
    windowHeight
  var init = function () {
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight
    _addEventHandlers()
  }
  var _addEventHandlers = function () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _checkPosition)
    window.addEventListener('resize', init)
  }
  var _checkPosition = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      var posFromTop = elems[i].getBoundingClientRect().top
      if (posFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
        elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace('hidden', 'fade-in-element')
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    init: init
  }
}
animateHTML().init()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element#scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to make the element visible in the viewport.

You can use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event to know when the DOM is ready.

**Note**: the options object - `{ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' }` is only supported by Chrome and Firefox. Other browsers support only a the `alignToTop` boolean, and since the object will evaluate to `true` the element will jump to the top.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.querySelector('.active').scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center'
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block active">Scroll into view</div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```